# Экранирование специальных символов в POST-запросе в C#

Tags: c#, экранирование

Я передаю из консольки в WCF-сервис строку:

```
"@ _ ^ { } \ [ ~ ] | ! " # & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ?"
```

Если прямо ее передавать, то мы получим ошибку

> Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (500) Внутренняя ошибка сервера.

Однако, если вручную экранировать эти символы `&amp;quot; &amp;amp;` и передавать так, то в таком же виде они и придут на сервис.
Как правильно экранировать в этом случае такие символы?

Comment: Покажите код, которым вы вызваете сервис

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332854(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

экранирование строки:

```
Uri.EscapeDataString(txt);
```